# Problem get data from an array using fetch API

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that tracks all the links on a page, check how the server responds and return the http requests.

The problem I'm encountering is that I'm not achieving get data from array. 
This is my code:

```
let a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
let code = [];


for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {

    let myRequest = a[i].href;
    let x = fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
        return response.status;
    })

    x.then(function(result) {
        code.push((result));
    })
}
 console.log(code); // [200, 200, ....]
 console.log(Array.isArray(code)); // true
 let codeOne = code[0];
 console.log(codeOne); // undefined ¿?¿?
```

Does anyone know how I can access to the data in the array? 
I don't know what else I can do ...

Answer (score 3):

You are working with promises (`fetch`) which means that you must wait that all the promises are resolved before checking the results.

To make it possible, you can use `Promise.all` that will run all the promises in parallel and wait for their results.

```
let a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 

//Create the array of promises
const linkPromises = a.map(aTag => fetch(aTag.href).then(response => response.status));

//Run the promises in parallel 
Promise.all(linkPromises).then(results => {
    //All promises are resolved

    console.log(results); // [200,200,...]

}).catch(error => {
    console.log("An error occurs " + error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, is when you are printing the values, the fetch didn't happened yet. Try do like this:

```
const tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
let code = [];

const promises = Array.from(tags).map(tag => fetch(tag));
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
        code = results.map(x => x.status);
        console.log('Status Codes: ', code);
        console.log('First status code: ', code[0]);
    });
```